# Zend_Form: Disabled checkbox behaves badly

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, checkbox

I am trying to add a disabled checkbox using Zend_Form and then enable it with JS.

Here's the problem, zend adds a hidden input field with the same name and the value 0. This is to make sure even if the checkbox is not checked a value of 0 will be sent rather than no value at all. This is great. But if you create your checkbox as disabled, zend does not output this hidden field. All it outputs is the checkbox, disabled, being checked or not (does not matter since it is disabled it wont submit anything at all).

I need to allow the client to enable the checkbox and change the value.

If it is disabled, nothing is submitted, the db checkbox value stays the same. If it is enabled the client should be able to check/uncheck it. The problem is now there is no hidden field, and if the checkbox is unchecked nothing is submitted.

Any ideas?

Comment: is it not possible to check your post using isset($_POST['checkboxname']) ?

Comment: No, see the comment to the first answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: I don't like the way Zend handled this for you. Adding the hidden field with value 0 simply isn't the same as a disabled checkbox, as you found out yourself.

To solve your problem: Simply add a hidden field by yourself with the original state in it.

eg:

```
<INPUT type="hidden" name="originalStateOfMyCheckbox" value="enabled/disable">
```

Now you can check the value of your checkbox by first checking the value of $_POST["originalStateOfMyCheckbox"].

If enabled: you can use isset($_POST["yourcheckboxname"]) to find out if it was checked.

If disabled: you can use again isset($_POST["yourcheckboxname"]) to find out if your javascript enabled it.

Comment: That wont work for me. I need a generalized way to handle stuff. Things such as adding custom HTML or checking each field inside $_POST is simply impossible. I am rendering the entire form with echo $form so adding html is out of the question, and as of the first thing, I call $form->populate($_POST) so again, checking each field is just out of the question. What if later I add another field to the database? I will have to modify code in places it's impossible to remember.

Comment: I don't see why that is a problem. You have a special case here (you are enabling a former disabled element). If that case doesn't fit into the straightjacket approach of Zend, you have to escape the prisoncell and fix your problem yourself.
In this case you could, for example, manipulate $_POST itself, and perform your checks on originalStateOfMyCheckbox and overwrite the values in $_POST of your checkbox (which is otherwise 0). Or better, make a copy of it and manipulate that, before feeding it to $form->populate($_POST).

Possibly somebody else has a better, more Zend-like, solution.

Comment: I found an easier solution, just removed the disabled attribute and added a class which then helps me identify which checkbox should be disabled/enabled, since this is only on the visual side anyway.

Comment: Great, but that is only visual indeed. The underlying formbehaviour stays of course the same. Glad you fixed it. :-)